# Empty string returned when executing Environment.GetFolderPath() in the context of IIS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, iis, path

### Problem

I have a desktop application which returns *"C:\Users\Mpaul\AppData\Local"* when calling `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)`.

I also have a web application which runs on the Local IIS Web Server; it too calls the same method but returns an empty string.

Interestingly enough, if I set the debug server to be Visual Studio's Development server (defined in the project's properties), it returns the correct path.

### Deductions

When running in the context of Visual Studio, `Environment.GetFolderPath()` works as expected.

When running in the context of IIS, it `Environment.GetFolderPath()` returns an empty string.

### Questions

Can the Environment class be used effectively in a web environment; or is there an alternative that works in both web and desktop environments?

Is there a special permission required for the `Environment.GetFolderPath()` method when ran in the context of IIS?

**Additional info**

Visual Studio 2008

IIS 7.5

Comment: I don't see any problems

Comment: @celsoap7 Interesting. What identity are you using? Do you have `loadUserProfile` and `setEnvironmentVariables` to true for your application pool in the `applicationHosts.config`?